# Python: Variable scope and parameters issue

Tags: python, python-3.4

**No `global` please.**

Here is my current code:

```
import random

def getSecretPhrase():
    secretPhrase = "I like trains,Drop the bass,YouTube is funny,Ebola is dangerous,Python is cool,PHS is 116 years old,I am a person,Sleep is overrated,Programming is fun".split(",")
    x = random.randint(1,10)
    correctPhrase = secretPhrase[x-1]
    print("Please guess a letter.")
    correctLetters = input().lower()
    return correctPhrase
def createPhrase():
    blanks = '_' * len(correctPhrase)
    print(blanks)
    print(correctPhrase)
def main():
    getSecretPhrase()
    createPhrase()
    for i in range(len(secretPhrase)):
        if correctPhrase[i] in correctLetters:
            blanks = blanks[:i]+correctPhrase[i] + blanks[i+1:]
    for letter in blanks:
        print(letter, end = ' ')
main()
```

The intended output should be:

```
Please guess a letter.
>>> e
#assuming the phrase is I like trains
_ - _ _ _ e - _ _ _ _ _ _
```

However, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Documents and Settings\Alex\My Documents\Downloads\az_wheeloffortune12.py", line 27, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Documents and Settings\Alex\My Documents\Downloads\az_wheeloffortune12.py", line 21, in main
        createPhrase()
      File "C:\Documents and Settings\Alex\My Documents\Downloads\az_wheeloffortune12.py", line 16, in createPhrase
        blanks = '_' * len(correctPhrase)
    NameError: name 'correctPhrase' is not defined
```

I am trying to use the variable `correctPhrase` in multiple places. This may be a scope issue.

Comment: This is a scope issue.  If you want to share a variable you either need it to be a global, you need to pass it to the function, or these need to be class methods and you store the variable as an instance variable or class variable

Comment: How would I do that? I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I answered below how you would do it in a class because that is how I'd do it.  However this seems like a homework assignment and I don't get the impression that you've learned about objects yet.  You'll probably want to work with passing arguments to functions instead of global variables or a class.

Comment: Yeah, we haven't learned about classes yet so that would look shady.

Comment: Your problem is that you aren't passing the variables into the appropriate functions, and then you aren't saving the return values from the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made alot of comments here, hopefully you can follow:

```
import random

def get_secret_phrase():
    # Instead of using one long string and creating a list from it, just make a list!
    phrases = ["I like trains","Drop the bass","YouTube is funny","Ebola is dangerous","Python is cool","PHS is 116 years old","I am a person","Sleep is overrated","Programming is fun"]
    # We have a list, we can get its length by using `len()` so there is no need to hardcode a value of 10
    # We also know that lists are 0-indexed, so we can tell `randint()` to get an int between 0 and the length of the list - 1
    index = random.randint(0, len(phrases) - 1)
    # Now we get the phrase at the random `index` we just created
    secret_phrase = phrases[index]
    # An alternative, more pythonic way to do the previous 2 lines is to use `random.choice()` which does the same logic
    #secret_phrase = random.choice(phrases)
    # Finally, return `secret_phrase` and make it lowercase so we can use it in another method
    return secret_phrase.lower()

def get_user_guess():
    # We want to make this separate from `get_secret_phrase()` because this will be called every time we want the user to guess
    print("What is your guess? ")
    # Assign the user input to a variable
    guess = input().lower()
    print("You guessed: {}".format(guess))
    return guess

def get_phrase_progress(secret_phrase, guessed_letters):
    # We want to generate a string that will represent how many letters the user has gotten correctly
    # We will call this every time so that it is always accurate based on what was guessed
    blanks = ''
    for letter in secret_phrase:
        if letter == ' ' or letter in guessed_letters:
            blanks = blanks + letter
        else:
            blanks = blanks + '_'
    return blanks

def get_phrase_progress_pythonic(secret_phrase, guessed_letters):
    # Here's a really pythonic way to do this
    return ''.join(letter if letter == ' ' or letter in guessed_letters else '_' for letter in secret_phrase)

def main():
    guessed_letters = list() # First, create a `list` to store the guessed letters
    secret_phrase = get_secret_phrase() # Next, call `get_secret_phrase()` and assign it's value to a variable in the scope of `main()`

    # Uncomment the following to see that the pythonic version returns the same thing
    # print(get_phrase_progress(secret_phrase, guessed_letters))
    # print(get_phrase_progress_pythonic(secret_phrase, guessed_letters))

    guessed_phrase = get_phrase_progress(secret_phrase, guessed_letters)
    # We want to loop until the user guesses the whole phrase
    while guessed_phrase != secret_phrase:
        print(guessed_phrase)
        # We call `get_user_guess()` to prompt the user to enter a letter
        letter = get_user_guess()
        # Next we want to make sure they entered just 1 letter
        # We can use the built in `str.isalpha()` to check if the string entered by the user is alphabetical and at least 1 character long
        if not letter.isalpha():
            # However, we only want them to guess a single letter, so we also check that the length == 1
            if len(letter) != 1:
                print('You need to guess something...')
            else:
                print('You can only guess a single letter, you tried to guess: {}'.format(letter))
        # Next we check if the user already guessed the letter, if so, tell them!
        elif letter in guessed_letters:
            print('You already guessed {}'.format(letter))
        else:
            guessed_letters.append(letter)
        # Here we calculate `guessed_phrase` every loop to make sure it always takes into account what letters have been guessed
        guessed_phrase = get_phrase_progress(secret_phrase, guessed_letters)

    # If the user escapes the while loop, they won, they guessed the secret phrase
    # We can calculate a score based on how many letters they guessed, this isn't great but it works for a simple scoring method
    print('You won! It took you {} guesses to guess {}'.format(len(guessed_letters), secret_phrase))

main()
```

Comment: Nicely done, it works. Is there a noobish way to write phraseProgress_pythonic in a simple way for beginners?

Comment: Whoopsies, i was reading it then I realized it was the same thing, haha

Comment: Can you edit the program so that the output only makes you guess one time, then fills the blanks with that one letter then tells you the correct phrase?

Comment: You have all the code you need to implement that. Its much easier than what i gave you. I cant do it all for you or you wont learn, but ill say that its easy to do in `main` just replace the while loop with what the logic you just provided.

Answer (score 1):

I made a few assumptions writing this.  The first is that you want to make this some sort of hangman like game where they keep guessing until they get it.  To that end I've made a class that does it for you.  The code is commented with explanations

```
import random
import string


class WordGuesser(object):
    ## We store the possible secret phrases as a class variable and make sure they're lower case
    secretPhrase = map(string.lower, ['I like trains', 'Drop the bass',
                                      'YouTube is funny', 'Ebola is dangerous',
                                      'Python is cool', 'PHS is 116 years old',
                                      'I am a person', 'Sleep is overrated',
                                      'Programming is fun'])

    def __init__(self): 
        ## We pick a secret phrase
        self.correctPhrase = WordGuesser.secretPhrase[random.randint(1,10)-1]
        self.length = len(self.correctPhrase)
        ## We pick our 'blank' phrase
        self.blankPhrase = ''.join(('_' if letter != ' ' else ' ')
                                    for letter in self.correctPhrase)

    def gameLoop(self):
        print self.blankPhrase
        ## as long as our blank phrase is wrong we continue
        while self.blankPhrase != self.correctPhrase:                 
            guess = raw_input("Please guess a letter.").lower() ## Their guess
            temp = ""
            for i in range(self.length): ## we fill in the word
                if self.correctPhrase[i] == guess:
                    temp += guess
                else:
                    temp += self.blankPhrase[i]
            self.blankPhrase = temp
            print self.blankPhrase ## display what they have so far


def main():
    game = WordGuesser()
    game.gameLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When run it'll look like this

```
>>> 
___________ __ ___
Please guess a letter.a
_____a_____ __ ___
Please guess a letter.e
_____a_____ __ ___
Please guess a letter.i
_____a__i__ i_ ___
Please guess a letter.o
__o__a__i__ i_ ___
Please guess a letter.u
__o__a__i__ i_ _u_
Please guess a letter.p
p_o__a__i__ i_ _u_
Please guess a letter.m
p_o__ammi__ i_ _u_
Please guess a letter.y
p_o__ammi__ i_ _u_
Please guess a letter.e
p_o__ammi__ i_ _u_
Please guess a letter.l
p_o__ammi__ i_ _u_
Please guess a letter.s
p_o__ammi__ is _u_
Please guess a letter.r
pro_rammi__ is _u_
Please guess a letter.g
programmi_g is _u_
Please guess a letter.n
programming is _un
Please guess a letter.f
programming is fun
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is clearly homework, I decided to try and implement it in as few lines of code as possible, just for fun. Got it down to 4...

```
import random
phrase, board, guesses, tries = random.choice(["I like trains", "Drop the bass", "YouTube is funny", "Ebola is dangerous", "Python is cool", "PHS is 116 years old", "I am a person", "Sleep is overrated", "Programming is fun"]).lower(), lambda guesses: ' '.join(letter if letter in guesses else "-" if letter == " " else "_" for letter in phrase), set(), 0
while board(guesses) != board(phrase.replace(" ", "-")): print board(guesses); guesses.add(raw_input("What is your guess? ").lower()); tries += 1
print "YOU WIN! It took you {} tries and {} unique guesses to guess {}".format(tries, len(guesses), board(guesses))
```

You can try it out here: http://repl.it/4cg

So to answer your original question...

```
import random

def getSecretPhrase():
    secretPhrase = "I like trains,Drop the bass,YouTube is funny,Ebola is dangerous,Python is cool,PHS is 116 years old,I am a person,Sleep is overrated,Programming is fun".split(",")
    x = random.randint(1,10)
    correctPhrase = secretPhrase[x-1]
    print("Please guess a letter.")
    correctLetters = input().lower()
    return correctPhrase
def createPhrase(correctPhraseArgument): # this method accepts an argument and stores it in a variable named `correctPhraseArgument`
    blanks = '_' * len(correctPhraseArgument)
    print(blanks)
    print(correctPhraseArgument)
def main():
    secretPhrase = getSecretPhrase() # assign the returned value to a variable in this scope
    createPhrase(secretPhrase) # pass the variable to this method
    for i in range(len(secretPhrase)):
        if correctPhrase[i] in correctLetters:
            blanks = blanks[:i]+correctPhrase[i] + blanks[i+1:]
    for letter in blanks:
        print(letter, end = ' ')
main()
```

This will still have issues, but I want to show you what is causing the error you mentioned...

The variables that are declared inside of your methods live inside those methods. To access them from other methods WITHOUT using global variables, you need to pass them as parameters and return the values. Then, you need to assign those returned values to new variables.

Comment: Wow that takes skill + python 3 please.

Comment: Nice little code golf there... and I did a Python 3 version, but there's an error at the end...can you find it?

Comment: @Player72 Not sure. I know it's a very simplified version of hangman, accepts multiple character inputs but doesnt use them, doesn't let you guess the whole phrase, and the scoring is meh xD If you mean there's an error in the python 3 version you made, there should only be 2 modifications needed, change `raw_input` to `input` and make the `print` statements into function calls. I have never actually used 3 before though, so i may be wrong.

Comment: yes that. here's the traceback `line 7, in <module>
    print ("YOU WIN! It took you {} tries and {} unique guesses to guess {}").format(tries, len(guesses), board(guesses))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'`

Comment: But i actually need help and i have no idea what lambda so keep it simple m8, but nice job

Comment: @Player72 You need to put the parenthesis at the end of that line, not just at the end of the string :) As for the help... With all the answers I assumed someone had helped you, I didnt actually check. I'll see if i can...

Comment: @Player72 I dont know if my edit helps, but I made some tweaks to your code and commented on them, and then summarized what was causing your error at the bottom. This does not fix the rest of your code, only the error you were seeing.

Comment: I understand the comments finally. However it doesn't work, `TypeError: createPhrase() missing 1 required positional argument: 'correctPhrase'`

Comment: @Player72 It's telling you that you that that method is expecting an argument, you need to pass it an argument when you call it.

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
import random

def getSecretPhrase():
    secretPhrase = "I like trains,Drop the bass,YouTube is funny,Ebola is dangerous,Python is cool,PHS is 116 years old,I am a person,Sleep is overrated,Programming is fun".split(",")
    x = random.randint(1,10)
    correctPhrase = secretPhrase[x-1]
    print("Please guess a letter.")
    correctLetters = input().lower()
    return correctPhrase
def createPhrase(correctPhrase):
    blanks = '_' * len(correctPhrase)
    print(blanks)
    print(correctPhrase)
def main():
    secretPhrase = getSecretPhrase()
    createPhrase(secretPhrase)
    for i in range(len(secretPhrase)):
        if correctPhrase[i] in correctLetters:
            blanks = blanks[:i]+correctPhrase[i] + blanks[i+1:]
    for letter in blanks:
        print(letter, end = ' ')
main()
```

Comment: It is not defined still.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not only "correctLetters", there are a lot of variable scope issue in your code.

correctLetters is defined in getSecretPhrase() and only alive in this method. So, the method() doesn't know what is correctLetters, that's why you see this exception.

There are a lot of ways to solve this issue

First is define the "correctLetters" outside the method, and using keyword global

Second you can return the variable, such as:

```
def createPhrase():

    blanks = '_' * len(correctPhrase)

    return blanks
```

so in main(), you can get the return value as:

```
blanks = createPhrase()
```

Comment: `TypeError: createPhrase() missing 1 required positional argument: 'correctPhrase'`

Comment: yes, you need init correctPhrase outside the method and use "global" keyword in main()

Comment: cannot use global i said it in the top of my post